# Adding rows changes the sum result with group by

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, ssms, ssms-2014

How do I add more columns without changing the result?

Currently this script gets the top 300 purchase order results by order value using a sum & grouping by the order items `oi.nettprice` This shows the correct results as shown below.

[Results shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4tIh.jpg)

```
select top 300

oi.orderid, o.traderid, o.orderdate, 

SUM(oi.nettprice) AS nettprice

from orderitems AS oi

INNER JOIN orders AS o ON o.tradertype = 'S' AND o.id = oi.orderid 

where oi.ordertype = 'PO'
AND oi.status != 'CANCELLED'

group by
oi.orderid, o.traderid, o.orderdate

order by
nettprice DESC
```

Adding any additional columns to show more information changes the results and alters the sum of `oi.nettprice` as shown below, I've tried to use group by rollup but this gives the value in a separate row with the other column values as NULL.

```
select top 300

oi.orderid, o.traderid,
o.orderdate, oi.partid, oi.description, oi.partrevisionid, 

SUM(oi.nettprice) AS nettprice

from orderitems AS oi

INNER JOIN orders AS o ON o.tradertype = 'S' AND o.id = oi.orderid

group by rollup 
(oi.orderid, o.traderid, o.orderdate, oi.ordertype, oi.status, oi.partid, oi.description, 
oi.partrevisionid)

HAVING oi.ordertype ='PO'
AND oi.status != 'CANCELLED'

order by
nettprice DESC
```

[Results using Group by rollup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC91G.jpg)

How can I clear this up to include columns from either table with the correct total (SUM) for each purchase order without affecting the results?

Answer (score 0):

Use sum() partition by to get the desired result

```
SELECT top 300 oi.orderid,
       o.traderid,
       o.orderdate,
       oi.partid,
       oi.description,
       oi.partrevisionid,
       SUM(oi.nettprice) OVER(PARTITION BY oi.orderid, o.traderid, o.orderdate)  AS nettprice
FROM orderitems AS oi
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON o.tradertype = 'S'
AND o.id = oi.orderid
WHERE oi.ordertype = 'PO'
AND oi.status != 'CANCELLED'
ORDER BY nettprice DESC
```

Comment: Hi Vijay, this gives results for each order line as a row with the same ordernettprice for each result. This is not going to give me the top 300 with a sum and the ability to add more columns from the tables without affecting the sum results. Thank you though

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).